# How to specify log file path with log4net.config?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

In my log4net.config I put

```
<appender name="Access" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%envFolderPath{CommonApplicationData}\MyApp\test.txt"/>
```

& my code for configuration is

```
    XmlDocument log4netConfig = new XmlDocument();
    log4netConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));
    var repo = log4net.LogManager.CreateRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(),
                               typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));

    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, log4netConfig["log4net"]);
```

but it didn't creating file at 【C:\ProgramData\MyApp】.

I also tried using

- %envFolderPath{ApplicationData}
- %envFolderPath{ProgramData}

Any ideas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Works fine on my machine. You can try to debug it with steps:

1. Try to log information to some hardcoded path like C:\temp to make sure, your configuration is working fine.
2. Add reference to `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` to make sure all librieries are in place
3. Use this line to configure log4net:

`XmlConfigurator.Configure(LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()), new FileInfo("log4net.config"));`

4. Make sure you have enough permission to write to Special Folders.
5. Create new Console Application in .net core with the same configuration, and enable internal debugging:

`log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;`

You will see exactly what's going on. You will see what paths your application is using and you will see any errors that occurs during internal log4net configuration.